# Link using a multivalued field and single valued field

Tags: sharepoint-online, connected-web-parts

I am trying to link two lists together using a connected webpart view. The columns that I would like to link are both multivalued (choice).

If an item in list A contains the values 1,2,3 in the linked column and an item in list B containts the values 1,2 in a linked column, I want that to count as a match in the webpart view so that both show when I click on the item in list A.

At the moment, it won't show since it is not an exact match (it will match only if both are 1,2,3.

Is there a way to do link the lists such that partial matches allow for a link?

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

It is not possible to achieve using connected web parts in SharePoint.

Connected web parts only works with exact match.